# BASH - Adding an argument that acts as a switch

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm currently working on a BASH script (unable to post as it's graded, however we are allowed to ask for GUIDANCE) and I've nearly completed it.

It uses the ls command a lot, and we need to make it so the user can choose whether or not they want the ls command to include human readable format of sizes or not. (i.e whether ls includes -h).

**I was wondering, is there a way to make it so that if the second argument of the script execution is -h, that all ls commands will include the -h option?**

Cheers!

Comment: `man getopt` is your answer

Answer (score 1):

The most simplistic way of doing this is

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == -h ]]
then
  flags="-h"
else
  flags=""
fi

ls -l $flags
```

You could then run

```
./yourscript -h
./yourscript
```

and it would run ls with and without `-h` respectively.

More robust solutions for parsing flags include `getopts`, which allow you to parse conventional Unix flag specifications like `./yourscript -e foo -d bar -vhq`. If you want your script to allow more than this single argument, you should look into that.

Comment: So, say I had a .txt file with the following information in columns

Size1 File1
Size2 File2

etc, How would I access the sizes, make them into human readable and replace all the sizes needed in the .txt file with the NEW sizes?

Answer (score 0):

If you're iterating over the results of `ls`, you need to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs . If you're using `ls` just to display files, you're OK.

To do option parsing in your script, use the bash builtin [`getopts`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-getopts) -- search for getopts here and I'm sure you find lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

try something like :

```
human=${option+-$option}
ls $human
example :
option="h"
echo ls $human 
ls -h
```